# Fiat Punto Evo 2010, headlight bulb not turning on

Tags: headlight, fiat, punto

I recently brought a used 2010 Fiat Punto Evo and I am having trouble understanding all the bulbs in there and when they turn on. One of the bulbs is not turning on with any setting.

Here is a picture of headlight with all turned off:
[Image 1 all off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IwY0.jpg)

Here is a picture of headlights on  1st setting (is this called daytime running light?). The small bulb in right lights up:
[Image 2 daylight running lights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tALoP.jpg)

Here is a picture of headlight on dipped beam. The small bulb is on and the middle bulb turns up.(the intensity is low as I reduced camera sensitivity to light):
[Image 3 dipped beam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTDFz.jpg)

Here is a picture of headlights on main beam. Both centre and right bulbs are on and higher intensity.
[Image 4 main beam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrA0x.jpg)

The thing is I am not sure when does the bulb on extreme left supposed to turn on? 
Am I missing some setting or is this a fault? If a fault please suggest things I should look for.

Also this behaviour is similar on the right headlight as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did some more looking around and found the owners handbook online that had the answer.

From image 1 in questing. The left bulb is for day time running lights, the center is dipped/main beam and the right small bulb is sidelight.

The setting "o" on control stick is daytime running lights. The "bulb" on stick is sidelights and the last is dipped lights.

As per my question the picture 1 is from setting 'o'. The second from 'bulb' and third from 'dipped' on the control stick.

My understanding of lights was wrong and the daytime running lights were not working but the sidelights were working in image 2.

Per owners handbook in the 'menu/esc' menu there is an option to turn on/off daytime running lights. I had this on off and hence the issue. I turned this to on and both left bulb turns on when on 'o' on lights control stick.